# Trying to use SHCreateShellItem, having #include issues

Tags: windows, com, winapi

There is a function in called `SHCreateShellItem` which is declared in `<shlobj.h>`, but it has been `#ifdef`'d out based on whether or not `_WIN32_IE` is greater than or equal to `0x601` (if it is, then the declaration is present). However, even when I define `_WIN32_IE` to `0x601` before I include `<shlobj.h>`, MSVC++ still complains that `SHCreateShellItem` is undeclared.

For example, I cannot get the following to compile:

```
#define _WIN32_IE 0x601
#include <shlobj.h>

int someFunction (LPITEMIDLIST parent, LPITEMIDLIST child)
{
    HRESULT result;
    IShellItem *shellObj;

    result = SHCreateShellItem (parent, NULL, child, &shellObj);
    if (SUCCEEDED(result))
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    return SUCCEEDED(result);
}
```

Do I need to define `_WIN32_IE` in a different way?

Comment: @Thomas: I still can't get it to work even after a clean.

Comment: compiles perfectly for me too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_WIN32_IE` is usually defined in your `stdafx.h` file. You must change it there.

Comment: Precompiled header woes! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define _WIN32_IE directly, do it implicitly with _WIN32_WINNT (which sets the target platform for the SDK includes)

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however I still the same deal, it is not declaring the function. Does this value get implicitly defined anywhere?

Comment: Possibly your IDE project settings predefine this constant? Although one would expect the code definition to override in this case.

Comment: If you define these variables in a header file theres always a risk that windows.h has been included before the header is included (especially if precompiled headers are being used).